# Add an input box for each dropped file in dropzone

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I have a drag drop box with dropzone.js. I allow multiple files upload (max 5 files at present). I have asked to add an ability for user to add description for each uploaded file.
The challenges I have:

1. Unable to determine how many files user dragged in zone
2. if I create text-boxes outside the zone, how do I tie them to each file correctly? I have set uploadMultiple to false and process one file at a time.
   For example user uploaded 3 images of home, store & warehouse and 1 pdf and add description of Invoices, how do I ensure that Invoices doe not end up with home or store when processing that file?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished something like this by using a custom template for how Dropzone shows the file in the queue. I started with [this example](https://www.dropzone.dev/bootstrap.html) from the Dropzone author that explains how to use a custom template when displaying files in the queue. I expanded on the example by adding an extra form input to the template.

```
<div class="table table-striped" class="files" id="previews">
  <div id="template" class="file-row">
    <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
    <div>
      <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
      <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
    </div>

    <!-- include a form field to collect the description -->
    <div>
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea id="description"
                data-name="description"
                rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- remainder of template removed for brevity -->
  </div>
</div>
```

## Issue #1

When you add the form element, if you specify a `name` attribute, only the value from the form element associated with the last file will be submitted when the file uploads because you have multiple form elements all with the same `name` attribute.

To get around this, I did not include a `name` attribute but instead used a `data-name` attribute. Then I added the form element's value to the form data when the file got sent using this code:

```
myDropzone = new Dropzone('form#myuploadform')
myDropzone.on(
    'sending',
    function (file, xhr, formData) {
        let description = file.previewElement.querySelector('textarea')
        formData.append(description.getAttribute('data-name'),
                        description.value)
    }
)
```

## Issue #2

Because the `id` values are specified in the template, they will be the same value for every file added to the queue which violates the HTML spec since `id` values must be unique. Further since the `for` attribute of the LABEL element references the `id` of the TEXTAREA this also breaks accessibility because the second and subsequent LABELs will all reference the first TEXTAREA.

I fixed this by appending the UUID value Dropzone assigns to every `file` object to the `id` and `for` attributes as the file is being added to the queue, which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72192491/645638).